# How to display random number after submission?

Tags: javascript, html, random

I would like to ask how to display random number after submission?

```js
var stampmonths = new Array("01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12");
var thedate = new Date();
document.getElementById('ref').value = document.write(
  stampmonths[thedate.getMonth()] +
  thedate.getDate() +
  thedate.getFullYear() +
  thedate.getSeconds()
);
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="submit" id="ref" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Not exactly clear what you're asking. Are you asking how to replace the value of the submit button or are you asking how to show just the random number after the submit button has been pressed?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. On the reload of the submitted form, the below scripts will change the button text.

If you don't want to reload the page then you need to use libraries like `jquery` to submit the form using `ajax`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="submit" id="ref" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
</body>

<script>
var stampmonths = new Array(   "01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12");

var thedate = new Date();
document.getElementById('ref').value = stampmonths[thedate.getMonth()] + thedate.getDate() + thedate.getFullYear() +   thedate.getSeconds();
</script>
</html>
```

You could use `Math.Random` along with this as below,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form>
    <input type="submit" id="ref" name="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
    </body>

    <script>
    var stampmonths = new Array(   "01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12");
    var rnd = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9) + 1);;
    var thedate = new Date();
    document.getElementById('ref').value = rnd.toString() + stampmonths[thedate.getMonth()] + thedate.getDate() + thedate.getFullYear() +   thedate.getSeconds();
    </script>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of the [preventDefault action](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) on the submit button's click event to cancel the submit action, then calculate the random number and show that on the page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="submit" id="ref" name="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>

    <script>
    var stampmonths = [   "01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12"];

    var submit_button = document.getElementById('ref');
    function stopDefAction(evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      // now, since we cancelled the submit action, handle the action yourself
      // in this case, it's setting the submit button to show a random number
      var thedate = new Date();
      evt.target.value = stampmonths[thedate.getMonth()] + thedate.getDate() + thedate.getFullYear() +   thedate.getSeconds();

    }
    submit_button.addEventListener( 'click', stopDefAction, false );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```